# Use value from another column if value = 0

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 columns with values, column A and column B. Column A never has 0 values, but Column B does, but not that many. I would rather use the values in column B, as they are more accurate, but if the value is 0, then I would like to use the value in the same row, but in column A. I would prefer then to have an additional column called C, that would store mostly values of column B, but if it is 0 in a particular row, it would have the value of column A. In excel this is easy, I just go: IF(B2=0,A2,B2). But I am not sure how to achieve this in SQL. Below is my code:

```
select 
date,
shift,
location as loc
Sum(columnA) as A,
Sum(columnB) as B,
from data
where date = (select max(date) from data)  
and loc in ('locationA','LocationB')
group by date, shift, location, columnA, columnB
order by date, shift
```

Below is what I am trying to achieve:

```
Date       Shift location   Value A     Value B     Value C
21-05-2018  Day  locationA  0.04122204  0.887057531 0.887057531
21-05-2019  Day  locationA  0.928499827 0.580402396 0.580402396
21-05-2020  Day  locationB  0.092689448 0           0.092689448
21-05-2021  Day  locationA  0.848076929 0.300175453 0.300175453
21-05-2022  Day  locationA  0.231515332 0           0.231515332
21-05-2023  Day  locationB  0.982522662 0.560335678 0.560335678
21-05-2024  Day  locationA  0.253062961 0.82718016  0.82718016
21-05-2025  Day  locationA  0.334965117 0           0.334965117
21-05-2026  Day  locationB  0.799616495 0.207699462 0.207699462
21-05-2027  Day  locationA  0.493148616 0.368975734 0.368975734
21-05-2028  Day  locationA  0.337537045 0.832800529 0.832800529
21-05-2029  Day  locationB  0.520104195 0.17532647  0.17532647
21-05-2030  Day  locationA  0.845699549 0           0.845699549
21-05-2031  Day  locationB  0.731698971 0.132675791 0.132675791
```

Comment: Is valueA = sum(columnA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ISNULL` and `NULLIF` to achieve the same as below:

```
SELECT 
ISNULL(NULLIF(ValueB, 0), ValueA) AS ValueC
FROM tableData
```

If it is frequently required then you can add computed column in the physical table itself which is more better approach than this.

OR

while inserting value to `ValueB` you can add the `CASE` in the same way, which is onetime task then you can select directly `ValueB` without any condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a case statement like this

```
case 
  when columnB=0
  then columnA
  else columnB
end as columnC
```

I do not understand the correlation of your output with your provided query and will refrain to comment on it.

However note that you can use case inside grouping functions like `SUM(case...)`  as well outside it like `case SUM(columnB)=0 then..`

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer

```
CASE
  WHEN ISNULL(columnB,0)=0
  THEN columnA
  ELSE columnB
END  AS  columnC
```

Comment: @Diacide try this answer,  i hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Create PERSISTED column. Here is how to create persisted column.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [Id] [int] NULL,
    [ColumnA] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ColumnB] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ColumnC]  AS (case when [ColumnB]=(0) then [ColumnA] else [ColumnB] end) PERSISTED NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```